# How can I get what my main function has returned?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

In a C program if we want to give some input from terminal then we can give it by:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

In the same way, if we want to get return value of `main()` function then how can we get it?

In each `main()` we write `return 1` or `return 0`; how can I know what my `main()` has returned at terminal?

**Edit:1**

I get it that by `echo $?` we can get the return value of `main()` but it only allows me to return a value less then 125 (in Linux) successfully. A return value more than that cannot be be successfully received by the `$ variable` so

**why is `int` the return type of `main()`? Why not keep it `short int`?**

**Edit2**

From where can I find out the meaning of the error code if `main()` returns a value greater than 125?

Comment: There's no real advantage to choosing `short` over `int` unless you have a lot of them in the same place (array or struct).  It's not faster to have a `short` and on modern ABIs you often don't even save space by choosing it.  In some places `short` is slower because you have to do sign extension when loading it.

Comment: surprised by one downvote..!!!

Comment: @Jeegar Patel....you must understand that some people are always haters

Comment: I think that is related to the size of the CPU registers.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Most shells store the exit code of the previous run command in `$?` so you can store or display it.

```
$ ./a.out
$ echo $?     # note - after this command $? contains the exit code of echo!
```

or

```
$ ./a.out
$ exit_code=$?    # save the exit code in another shell variable.
```

Note that under linux, although you return an `int`, generally only values less than 126 are safe to use. Higher values are reserved to record other errors that might occur when attempting to run a command or to record which signal, if any, terminated your program.

Comment: I don't know of a UNIX flavor that keeps more than the lowest 8 bits.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone: I've just checked the bash man page, and it's actually less than I remembered. If you attempt to use >125 you may collide with values that the shell uses. I'm not certain about other shells.

Comment: Good point. Unix allows up to 255 at the OS level, but it doesn't dictate that the shell preserve all of those...

Answer (score 40):

Your shell probably has a special variable `$?`, which holds the last program returned value. So, soon after your program finishes, you can run:

```
echo $?
```

to see the returned value.

Comment: Only the low 8-bits are interpreted (that's why the value returned must be in the range 0-255). The 127 comes from the representation of negative integers which are then interpreted as unsigned.

Comment: @sidyll: I think you mean 7-bits, not 8-bits. The low 8-bits of -1 would be 255, the low 7-bits are 127.

Comment: @eharvest: I don't understand your working. -1 is a lot of ones, truncate that to 8 bits and treat as an signed and you still have -1, treat it as unsigned and you have 255.

Answer (score 32):

In DOS/Windows you can use `errorlevel` within a batch file

```
executable optional arguments
if errorlevel 4 goto LABEL4
if errorlevel 3 goto LABEL3
if errorlevel 2 goto LABEL2
if errorlevel 1 goto LABEL1
:SUCCESS
echo SUCCESS; errorlevel 0
goto :eof
:LABEL1
echo FAILURE; errorlevel 1
goto :eof
:LABEL2
echo FAILURE; errorlevel 2
goto :eof
REM ...
```

Just remember to check from the greatest to the lowest because `if errorlevel 42` really means "if errorlevel is 42 or greater"

Comment: +1 @Alex: good point. In my defence I only noticed the tag after I started writing the answer --- and decided to complete and post it

Comment: +1 Good answer. I was looking for a Windows specific method, which probably doesn't need a separate question.

Comment: +1 as it's still nice to be able to look this up in one place in the future (even though I hardly ever work in windows)

Answer (score 5):

Summarizing comments and bits and pieces so they're in one place.

A C program always has an **exit code**, which the program may decide for itself if it terminates normally, by returning a value from the `main` function or by calling the `exit` function. If the program terminates abnormally, for example by a segmentation fault, the operating system decides the exit code.

In Unix (Posix), the exit code is an 8-bit value: 0-255. It is combined with some other metadata to a **status**: the other metadata includes information about whether the program terminated normally or not, if it was terminated because of a signal, and if so, which signal. For details, see the [wait(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) manual page.

In Unix, at the shell, the status of the previous command is accessible as the `$?` special variable. Because the exit code is only 8 bits, and it's treated as an unsigned integer, if you return a negative value, it gets turned into a positive one: -1 becomes 255. Likewise, if you return a value greater than 255 only the least significant 8 bits are used: 256 becomes 0.

The return type of `main` is `int`, rather than `short` or `char`, because there's no particular benefit in making it a smaller type, particularly at this point in history, decades after it was decided. Changing it now would only cause unnecessary complications.

If you want to execute a program from C, the standard library provides the `system` function, which handily returns the status of the program. (Note that `system` runs commands via the shell, and you need to be very careful about escaping everything correctly if you give the command any externally provided filenames or other things on the command line.)

For more flexibility, you can execute other programs using the system calls `fork`, `execl` (or one of its variants, see the [exec(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) manual page), and `wait` (already mentioned above). This is powerful and flexible, but it's also easy to make mistakes, so be sure to read the documentation and check out some example programs first. (On the other hand, it's very much fun to learn this stuff.)

Answer (score 3):

You can get the exit values with the command basic linux command
echo $?
The error codes are standard and the details are explained in this
[link](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html)

The general codes are

**

0- success

1- general errors

126- permission issue

127-Illegal command

128-Invalid arguments and fatal errors

255-Out of range**

Answer (score 1):

> in windows command line to read return value from main
> use  ***echo  %errorlevel%***

### (Code) return.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int i;

    printf("Enter a number");
    scanf("%d",&i);

   if(i==2)
        exit(1);
   if(i==3)
        exit(2);
    
   return 0;
}
```

### OUTPUT

[**OUTPUT** of above program **return.c**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LstCk.png)

Comment: Thanks man.  I have asked for linux only but its good to know about windows also here.

Comment: in windows cmd, use `echo %errorlevel%` after running executable.