# Why is the returned value different?

Tags: c++, return-value

I compiled a  two simple programs in c++ using making minor changes in each one and used the query `echo $?` to output the value returned to the OS by main.

**Program 1**

```
    int main()
    {
          return 0 ; 
    }
```

**Program 2**

```
   int main()
   {
       return -1 ; 
   }
```

When I ran the first program and did `echo $?` the value was as expected 0, but when I ran the second program and did `echo $?` the value was 255 instead of the expected -1.
Why is this so?
I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS in case it matters

Comment: Linux only uses the least significant 8 bits of the return from `main()` and treats it as a unsigned number.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: You should post that as the answer (I was just about to).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the valid range for program return value in Linux/bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082953/what-is-the-valid-range-for-program-return-value-in-linux-bash)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [POSIX spec for `exit()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exit.html):

> The value of status may be 0, EXIT_SUCCESS, EXIT_FAILURE, or any other value, though only the least significant 8 bits (that is, status & 0377) shall be available to a waiting parent process.

And per the C standard:

> a return from the initial call to the main function is equivalent to calling the exit function with the value returned by the main function as its argument;

Answer (score 1):

Linux uses only a byte of the return value. There is a very good, although somewhat lengthy explanation in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626109/how-can-i-get-what-my-main-function-has-returned). Check the one not marked as answer.