# Is there a return value if cmake BUILD directory is up to date?

Tags: makefile, cmake

I am building a cmake application, I'd like to know if there is a simple way to get a return value from cmake BUILD directory when it is up to date?

For example, if I see `[100%] Built target blahblah` when I type `make` in that BUILD dir, then I hope to get a value `1`.

Comment: why though? assuming you are on *nix, make wont rebuild anything. my project i just do make clean && cmake . && make. it doesnt rebuild anything it doesnt have to (if i had omitted make clean)

Comment: Say I'd like to do `if [buildStatus==upToDate] then cd .. && rm -rf BUILD`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626109/how-can-i-get-what-my-main-function-has-returned this might be of some use then. so it would probably be something like: cmake theDirectory; if [$? -eq 1]; then cd .. rm -rf BUILD; fi;

Comment: disclaimer: bash is not my strong suit so there are probably problems with the code i just wrote

Comment: Okay, perhaps I can just do a `make | grep 100%`

Comment: You want to know when running `make` will do no work?

Answer (score 0):

```
make -q && echo "Up-to-date"
```

or

```
make -q || echo "Work to do"
```

From the make [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/make):

> -q, --question
>
> ''Question mode''. Do not run any commands, or print anything; just return an exit status that is zero if the specified targets are already up to date, nonzero otherwise.

Comment: How so? Does make, in fact, have nothing to do? "Something to do" can involved a lot of things before the build output you expect I believe.

Comment: Don't know. You can try a cmake test case yourself and see that I am not lying. My make command shows [100%], however this solution gives "Work to do"

Comment: I don't know cmake at all. This isn't really related to cmake either (not exactly). What do you get as output if you run `make VERBOSE=1`?

Comment: A lot! It covers 1/3 of my screen so that I cannot paste them here. So I guess cmake use a different strategy for makefile, maybe?

Comment: @Daniel No, much of that may not matter. It looks like `-q` may not be useful for default/`all`/`.PHONY` targets though since those always need to be "rebuilt". That's a bit unfortunate if I'm interpreting what I'm seeing correctly. If you have a specific target that your default target proxies for you should be able to run `-q` against that and get a meaningful result though.